# Sum of geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let's say I have the series:
$1+(x+1)+(x+1)^2….$ if $|x+1|<1$, what is the sum of infinite geometric series?

This is my thinking:

I have the formula 
$S= a \dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r}$ 
Now we know that the ratio is between negative one and one, meaning that as the series approaches infinitey the number will approach zero. That gives us:

$S = a \dfrac{1-0}{1-r}$

$a = 1$

$r = x+1$

$S = \dfrac{1}{1-(x+1)}$

$S = \dfrac{1}{-x}$

I got this question wrong, and was not given any justification as to why. Any illumination would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks fine to me with the extra info $ -2 < x < 0 $.